# present perfect and past simple in this case

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

- > I have given your article about networking to professor.
- > I gave him your article and he has it now.

Both sentences mean the same:so why one is present perfect and the other past simple  both have the same efect on now 
Is it because in the first sentence it is more precise (article about networking)

Comment: Why did you use present perfect in the first example?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use the present perfect, you can talk about an action done at any time in the past.

Considering periods of time, you can have the following comparison:

- *I have given your article to the professor.* (Considering the whole period of the day up to the present.)
- *I gave your article to the professor.* (Early in the morning, so no present relevance is made.)

Comment: Absolute answer!